Powershell to organise output in a chart type
Hi i have the followign PS script but the output is not how i would like to arrange it, can anyone pelase help get it right please.
Its pollign a txt file for line with Name and Expire and i would like to dispaly this into a CSV with column heading of Name and Expire and have each name and expiry date int hat line to be stored :
ID         Name        Expire

ID1        Name1       01/11/2024
ID2        Name2       05/12/2025
ID3        Name3       04/12/2024

My current PS script :
$txtFilePath = "C:\Reports\key.txt"

$pattern1 = "id" 
$pattern2 = "names"
$pattern3 = "expires" 

$extractedData = @()

$lines = Get-Content -Path $txtFilePath
foreach ($line in $lines) {
if ($line -match $pattern1) {
$id = $line -replace '.*id*', ''
$extractedData += [pscustomobject]@{
  'Field' = '$line'
  'Value' = $id
   }
}
elseif ($line -match $pattern2) {
  $expires = $line -replace '.*name*', ''
  $extractedData += [namepscustomobject]@{
       'Field' = 'name'
       'Value' = $name
    }
}
    elseif ($line -match $pattern3) {
    $Expiry = $line -replace '.*expires*', ''
    $extractedData += [pscustomobject]@{
    'Field' = 'Expiry'
    'Value' = $Expiry
}
}
}


 $extractedData | Format-Table -AutoSize

 $extractedData | Export-Csv -Path "C:\Reports\Results\output.csv" -NoTypeInformation

Example of Key.txt:
{
"attributes": {
  "created": "2019-07-03T14:55:51+00:00",
  "enabled": true,
  "expire": "2299-12-25T07:28:38+00:00",
  "notBefore": null,
  "recoverableDays": 90,
  "recoveryLevel": "Recoverable",
  "updated": "2022-09-26T20:32:13+00:00"
 },
 "contentType": "",
"id": "https://prod-ukb2c-keyvault- 
ne.vault.azure.net/secrets/azure-log-analytics-workspace- 
customer-id",
"managed": null,
"name": "azure-log-analytics-workspace-customer-id",
"tags": {}
  },
  {

Here is an extract from key.txt :
},
"contentType": "text/plain; tfmanaged=true",
"id": "https://prodtctkvne.vault.azure.net/secrets/prod-helios",
"managed": null,
"name": "prod-helios-ado-app-secret",
"tags": {}
},
{
"attributes": {
"created": "2023-12-07T09:52:56+00:00",
"enabled": true,
"expires": null,
"notBefore": null,
"recoverableDays": 90,
"recoveryLevel": "Recoverable",
"updated": "2023-12-07T09:52:56+00:00"
},
"contentType": "text/plain; tfmanaged=true",
"id": "https://prodtctkvne.vault.azure.net/secrets/prod-helios",    
"managed": null,
"name": "prod-helios-databricks-app-id",
"tags": {}
},


Can you share sample input data (the contents of C:\Reports\key.txt)?

An example of the current results would also be useful.

Here is the data from key.txt

Thanks the formatting was changed to get it posted: wasnt sure how to attach to the actual request.  I tried your tip but i got a loud of exceptions ?

No, your example is invalid with an open { at the end, it has nothing to do with formatting. You need to post a [mcve] so that everyone can try and debug it. To address anyone you need to use @user or comment on their post. And please [edit] the question to include all the needed information: correct example input, what errors you get...

Your formatting is terrible but assuming the input is like this without the incorrect line breaks in the middle of the id strings
{
    "attributes": {
        "created": "2019-07-03T14:55:51+00:00",
        "enabled": true,
        "expire": "2299-12-25T07:28:38+00:00",
        "notBefore": null,
        "recoverableDays": 90,
        "recoveryLevel": "Recoverable",
        "updated": "2022-09-26T20:32:13+00:00"
    },
    "contentType": "",
    "id": "https://prod-ukb2c-keyvault-ne.vault.azure.net/secrets/azure-log-analytics-workspace-customer-id",
    "managed": null,
    "name": "azure-log-analytics-workspace-customer-id",
    "tags": {}
},
{
// More similar objects
}

then the file is actually kind of json with a list of objects without a root element. You can simply use ConvertFrom-Json to operate on it after adding a valid root array object [] like this
PS C:\> "[$(Get-Content C:\Reports\key.txt)]" | ConvertFrom-Json | `
    Select-Object -Property name, id, `
        @{Name="attributes.expire"; Expression={($_.attributes.expire -as [datetime]).ToString("MM-dd-yyyy")}}

name  id  attributes.expire
----  --  -----------------
name1 id1 12-25-2299
name2 id2 12-25-2123

@{Name="name"; Expression={...}} is used to create a user-defined property
